# I have button that execute my method but ignoring the if statement

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have a problem. iam making a game that have button for buy item , and the button have no issue, it run normally, but the problem is the button immediately executes the method without seeing that the method contains an if statement, so what is wrong here Here's the code :

```
     public void TakeMoney()
     {
         int minusCoin = PlayerInfo.coin -= 5;
         PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MyCoinAmount", minusCoin);
     }

     public void DisableBuyButton()
     {
         disableBuyButtonRocket3 = 1;
         PlayerPrefs.SetInt("DisableBuyButtonRocket3",  disableBuyButtonRocket3);
     }

     public void Buy()
     {
         int getPlayerCoin = PlayerInfo.coin;
         if (getPlayerCoin > 4)
         {
             if (MyRocket._rocket3 == 1)
             {

                 GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();

                 MyRocket._rocket3 = 1;
                 PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Rocket3Bought", MyRocket._rocket3);
             }
         }

     }
```

so the button will perform all of the 3 functions above, but as can be seen that I make an if statement so the item can only be purchased if we already have enough money, but when I try I try to reset all values, so my money by default it is 0, but I can buy the item and my money becomes a minus.

Btw, PlayerInfo above is a script from another scene.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Why are you using temporary variables everywhere? Also, why not combine all of these into a single method?

Comment: Could you share how your button is set up? It sounds like you've got all three of these methods attached to the button's OnClick event, is that correct?

Comment: please never do this `int minusCoin = PlayerInfo.coin -= 5;`

Comment: Also `if(MyRocket._rocket3 == 1)` and then set it to `1` and always store `1` in the `PlayerPrefs` seems odd to me..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you do everything in separated methods. It's basically not a problem - but, when you execute them concurrently, it is. Also, your methods are completely independent of each other - an `if` statement in one will not affect the others' execution. The solution is that you first remove the event listeners to `TakeMoney` and `DisableBuyButton`. Then, call them from `Buy`. If you think it through, it is more logical. Also, remove the temporary variables, as they slow down your code a bit and also make it less readable. Final code could be something like this:

```cs
public void TakeMoney()
{
    PlayerInfo.coin -= 5;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MyCoinAmount", PlayerInfo.coin);
}
public void DisableBuyButton()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("DisableBuyButtonRocket3", 1);
}
public void Buy()
{
    if (PlayerInfo.coin > 4) {
        TakeMoney();
        DisableBuyButton();
        if (MyRocket._rocket3 != 1 /* changed this, because it seemed that you want to check whether it is NOT one */)
        {
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
            // I changed the if statement because this
            MyRocket._rocket3 = 1;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Rocket3Bought", MyRocket._rocket3);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

the playerinfo.coin value would be more than 4 because it will decrease coin at click so it will minus only 5 at a click you could check playerinfo.coin value